# AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command' when building a bot for Discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have typed this code:

```
@bot.command(name="give", description="get a random YouTube video based on your prompt")
async def give_youtube_video(ctx: SlashContext, youtube_prompt: str):
    try:
        youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, developerKey='MY_DEV_KEY')

        search_response = youtube.search().list(
            q = youtube_prompt,
            type="video",
            part="id",
            maxResults=50
          ).execute()
        
        videos = search_response.get("items", [])
        if not videos:
            await ctx.send("shit prompt, no videos.")
            return
        
        video = random.choice(videos)
        video_id = video["id"]["videoId"]
        video_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}"

        await ctx.send(f"here's your video.")
    except HttpError as e:
        await ctx.send(f"there was an oopsie while fetching your video. Try again either now or later.")

# run
bot.run(DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN)
```

When debugging:
`[file path] AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'`
How can i fix this? Used modules are discord, discord.ext, commands, Bot and other unrelated modules such as stuff for google and youtube. Basically what it does is you input "!give [youtube_prompt]" and it gives you a random video from YouTube based on your prompt.

I would really appreciate it if someone reached out, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you initialize the bot [like this](https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/#using-bot-commands)?

```py
from discord.ext import command

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(name='give')
async def give_youtube_video(ctx: SlashContext, youtube_prompt: str):
    ...
```

If you intitialize it like this, it won't work:

```py
bot = discord.Client()
```

Comment: Also don't forget the intents. The bot wont start without intents.

`bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix="!",intents=discord.Intents.all())`

And import discord too

Comment: @jolammi The bot now logs in, and is online in Discord, but does not respond to the command in servers. Everything seems okay in my code, therefore I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Good addition by @Rexy.  Do you have the intents in your code?